# Custom compile error when type is used as action parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stylecop

I'm implementing an Identifier type library for a group of web applications and I want to mark some types as unfit for sending to the client / receiving from the client for compliance reasons.

Using the variable itself will cause no run time errors or issues, it's just unsafe to send out to the client due to security reasons.

Preferably I'd like to cause a compilation error when a banned type is used as an action parameter to give developers instant feedback and a nice experience.

An example of what I'm currently using:

```
public interface IInternalIdentifier {}

public class NonCompliantType : IInternalIdentifier {}

[ApiController]
public class BananaController : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Cavendish(int good, NonCompliantType bad)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Would throw something like:

```
Error: Type [NonCompliantType : IInternalIdentifier] Cannot be used as an action parameter.
```

Does C# have any built in way of doing something like this?

We are also using StyleCop, is there a way to create a rule that can do this?

This could be done using a unit test or at run time using reflection, however my goal here is to give developers immediate feedback on how they're using these types and keep the application as clean as possible.

Unit tests could be a 10-15min delay and runtime would slow start-up times or potentially cause issues in production.

Our old code base is currently using a reflection based unit test however since this library will be used in any number of web applications and microservices, making sure each one has an equivalent test would be cumbersome and error prone.

Comment: Use `custom model binder` and use `reflection` to check the type parameter and throw an exception if it is `BadType`.

Comment: Make it an internal type, perhaps in a separate project. Not sure if you'd need a custom model binder, but that would work too.

Comment: StyleCop has been superseded by [Roslyn Analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019). In fact, most StyleCop rules have been migrated to Roslyn Analyzers. You can create your own analyzer that would emit a warning or error if a certain condition is encountered, and even offer a fix.  Several libraries, eg NuGet and xUnit include analyzers for common code issues

Comment: The [Getting started with Roslyn Analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019) section shows how to create your own analyzer. A step-by-step guid can be found in [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix]9https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts:

1. You could split up your project into a few assemblies where the assembly for the web application code doesn't have access to the assembly containing the banned types. But there will be one or more assemblies in the middle that can access both sides (if you want).
2. A style cop rule should be possible.
3. My personal choice would be to add some start-up code that uses reflection to inspect all the controller action methods and crashes the application if it finds any types it doesn't like.

Comment: Hi Mike, Unfortunately controllers / services may still need to internally reference these types so they need to remain visible to the web assembly. Adding code that crashes an application at startup is extremely risky for large applications, and it's very frustrating for developers when applications crash on purpose, these types may be used in many different applications as well, which would make copy pasting the crash code a pain.

Comment: @Serdalis your comment makes no sense, sorry - you seem to prefer to wait for app to reach method that can't work and crash randomly which is strange. There is really not much to do short of reflection to see what action type parameters are to do what you want... If you happen to have developers that run unit tests you can do the same as test... but otherwise I don't see any other route than crash on startup when your reflection code detects invalid types in as action parameters...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've added more information in the question. Hopefully this will be enough to give more context to the question / comments.